# Not able to add value into database from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a cascading dropdownlist ,using razor view syntax. 
Both are populated from database and the 2nd dropdownlist is populated with ajax method.

```
1.  @Html.DropDownList("LevelMaster", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["LevelMaster"], "Select Master")

2.  <select id="BranchID" name="Branch"></select>
```

When i am trying to insert values into database using the these two dropdown selected value.
Getting an error :

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'LevelMaster'.

 <span>
  @Html.DropDownList("LevelMaster", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["LevelMaster"], "Select Master")
 </span>
```

Need some help.

Comment: How do you acquire you data before saving it in database? Do you submit a form?

Comment: you should show us how you are sending the values

Comment: @JesseJames: Like i have said before, i have populated the data from database in the dropdownlist.

Comment: @faby: I have told you what is my query. What do u need more to know?

Comment: I've answered, let me know if it was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is because you have `ViewData["LevelMaster"]` and at the same time `LevelMaster` is the name of your dropDownList. Try changing the name in `ViewData` something like `ViewData["LevelMasterViewData"]`

Answer (score 1):

For DropDownList you need to provide which item you have to display as well as which will be the displayed for complex type.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("LevelMaster", new SelectList(ViewData["LevelMaster"], "Level", "Price"), "--Default--")
```

Better option would be using a DropDownListFor with model property assigned to collect the value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.LevelMaster, new SelectList(ViewData["LevelMaster"], "Level", "Price"), "--Default--")
```

Where `LevelMaster` is of type `string`.